# Explain postgres query, why is the query that much longer with WHERE and LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I'm using postgres v9.6.5. I have a query which seems not that complicated and was wondering why is it so "slow" (it's not really that slow, but I don't have a lot of data actually - like a few thousand rows).

Here is the query:

```
SELECT o0.* 
FROM "orders" AS o0 
JOIN "balances" AS b1 ON b1."id" = o0."balance_id" 
JOIN "users" AS u3 ON u3."id" = b1."user_id" 
WHERE (u3."partner_id" = 3) 
ORDER BY o0."id" DESC LIMIT 10;
```

And that's query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..12.84 rows=10 width=148) (actual time=0.062..53.866 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..4750.03 rows=3826 width=148) (actual time=0.061..53.864 rows=4 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (b1.user_id = u3.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 67404
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..3945.32 rows=17856 width=152) (actual time=0.025..38.457 rows=16852 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using orders_pkey on orders o0  (cost=0.29..897.80 rows=17856 width=148) (actual time=0.016..11.558 rows=16852 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using balances_pkey on balances b1  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=16852)
                    Index Cond: (id = o0.balance_id)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.19 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=4 loops=16852)
              ->  Seq Scan on users u3  (cost=0.00..1.18 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.023..0.030 rows=4 loops=1)
                    Filter: (partner_id = 3)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 12
Planning time: 0.780 ms
Execution time: 54.053 ms
```

I actually tried without `LIMIT` and I got quite different plan:

```
Sort  (cost=874.23..883.80 rows=3826 width=148) (actual time=11.361..11.362 rows=4 loops=1)
  Sort Key: o0.id DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.77..646.55 rows=3826 width=148) (actual time=11.300..11.346 rows=4 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (o0.balance_id = b1.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on orders o0  (cost=0.00..537.56 rows=17856 width=148) (actual time=0.012..8.464 rows=16852 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=3.55..3.55 rows=18 width=4) (actual time=0.125..0.125 rows=24 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.21..3.55 rows=18 width=4) (actual time=0.046..0.089 rows=24 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (b1.user_id = u3.id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on balances b1  (cost=0.00..1.84 rows=84 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.029 rows=96 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.18..1.18 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=4 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on users u3  (cost=0.00..1.18 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.021 rows=4 loops=1)
                                Filter: (partner_id = 3)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 12
Planning time: 0.569 ms
Execution time: 11.420 ms
```

And also without `WHERE` (but with `LIMIT`):

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..4.74 rows=10 width=148) (actual time=0.023..0.066 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..7696.26 rows=17856 width=148) (actual time=0.022..0.065 rows=10 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (b1.user_id = u3.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 139
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..3945.32 rows=17856 width=152) (actual time=0.009..0.029 rows=10 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using orders_pkey on orders o0  (cost=0.29..897.80 rows=17856 width=148) (actual time=0.007..0.015 rows=10 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using balances_pkey on balances b1  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=10)
                    Index Cond: (id = o0.balance_id)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.21 rows=14 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=15 loops=10)
              ->  Seq Scan on users u3  (cost=0.00..1.14 rows=14 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=16 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.286 ms
Execution time: 0.097 ms
```

As you can see, without `WHERE` it's much faster. Can someone provide me with some information where can I look for explanations for those plans to better understand them? And also what can I do to make those queries faster (or I shouldn't worry cause with like 100 times more data they will still be fast enough? - 50ms is fine for me tbh)

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL thinks that it will be fastest if it scans `orders` in the correct order until it finds a matching `users` entry that satisfies the `WHERE` condition.

However, it seems that the data distribution is such that it has to scan almost 17000 `orders` before it finds a match.

Since PostgreSQL doesn't know how values correlate across tables, there is nothing much you can do to change that.

You can force PostgreSQL to plan the query without the `LIMIT` clause like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (<your query without ORDER BY and LIMIT> OFFSET 0) q
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

With a top-N-sort this should perform better.